# Linker errors when disabling defauly lib and CRT

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to build a C++ program without using CRT however I am getting the following Linker errors and cannot find a solution online. I can fix them by enabling CRT default lib but that defeats my goal.

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____acrt_iob_func
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____stdio_common_vfprintf
```

Disabling default lib is totally new to me and I am wondering if anyone on here has came across these errors before and found a solution?

Comment: It seems you need the features of a certain library.  WHY would you decline to use that library?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand that but I do not know which library Is required. I do not want to enable all of CRT to reduce the overall size of my program.

Comment: The linker extracts the necessary items from the library to place in the executable.  it does not load the whole library. (unless using a very old, obsolete loader.)

Comment: You made me think about this in a different way and I have solved my issue by including the default lib in the linker settings. I would accept as answer if I could. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved this by enabling default lib in VS project settings.

Project->Properties->Linker->Input->Ignore All Default Libraries->Set to NO.

Only the required lib will be imported into your project.

Answer (score 0):

You might find [Linkers and Loaders](http://linker.iecc.com/) interesting.  To answer your question requires understanding the difference between an object file and an executable program.

From the simplest point of view, C++ doesn't define I/O in the *language*.  It leaves that to a library, typically the default CRT in the case of Windows.  Any useful program has to have some input and create some output.  How to do that without I/O?

Programs usually run in the context of an operating system; these are called *hosted* because the OS provides services and arranges for them to run on the machine.  Specialized embedded programs -- maybe on you microwave oven, for example, or in your car -- run directly on the computer without the aid of an OS.  Such embedded programs get their input and output from hardware ports and interrupts, and don't have any use for the functions in the default runtime library.

If you're interested in developing an embedded system or replacing the CRT with something else, then you would want to disable linking to the CRT.  But a better platform for that IMO would be NetBSD.

Comment: Thank you James for the thorough explanation and also for the reference which I will check out. The main reason I wanted to try disable CRT which I knew would be a challenge, is to reduce the size of my program and also to learn more about how CRT works. I had many linker errors initially and reduce them down to just these two by linking to required libs but I cannot find anything on these two.